# Data table sorting is not working properly

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

friend please help me...
i am facing problem regarding data table sorting when i click on sort button in asc its show some rendom id like first row id is 20 second row is 18 like that

```
var dataTable = $('#users').DataTable( {    
              "bProcessing": true,
              "aLengthMenu": [[10,25,50,1000000,], [10,25,50,"All",]],
              "bProcessing": true,
              "serverSide": true,
              "language": {
                   searchPlaceholder: "Enter Card Number"
              },

              "dom": 'lfrtip',
              "ajax":{
                   url :"response.php",
                   type: "post",
              }
```

[image]

Comment: You are using serverSide procesing. Then the problem is on your php code. Show what have you done if you want our help.

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Are you using serverside sorting? if yes then make sure the field which you want sorting must be INT  datatype or relevant to numeric datatype in database.